# HTTPS header issue with Chrome version 44.0.2403.xx

Tags: wordpress, apache, google-chrome, https, request-headers

I have been struggling since I have installed the new Chrome version 44.0.2403.xx.

My initial issue was that some stylesheet on my website were load over https, but my website is only http.

I use wordpress, so I have searched inside the core function to find where the HTTPS was added into the url.

The culprit is the `is_ssl()` function. Wordpress base is HTTPS verification over the `$_SERVER['HTTPS']` variable, and mine was set to 1.

I found out that the last Google Chrome version is sending a header `HTTPs = 1`.

How can I prevent this header to cause problems to my website?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Wordpress (WooCommerce?) forces https (when it shouldn't)](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31565155/wordpress-woocommerce-forces-https-when-it-shouldnt)

Answer (score 3):

To solve my issue I have enabled `mod_header` on the server and added this rule to my `appache2.conf` file:

```
<IfModule mod_headers.c>
  RequestHeader unset HTTPS
</IfModule>
```

Comment: This works for servers that use Apache (since it's modifying the .htaccess file). Not the case with most NGINX servers.

The root problem is WP sites using anything less that WooCommerce 2.3.13. Reference the problem solution here http://superuser.com/a/943989

Comment: You are right about the NGINX, but it doesnt only come from WooCommerce, Wordpress Core contains a function that uses the https header: [is_ssl()](https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/is_ssl) .
In my case the problem occured when i used the [get_template_directory_uri()](https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/get_template_directory_uri) function

Comment: If your dont run apache, you could temporary fix it by setting the $_SERVER['http'] = false; in the wp-config.php.

Comment: Pierre: The WordPress core code only checks the `$_SERVER['HTTPS']` variable. That won't cause the issue, because the variable that causes problems from Chrome is coming in as `$_SERVER['HTTP_HTTPS']`. Core is not affected by this, but many plugins might be.

Comment: Well i can assure you that my var was $_SERVER['https']... that why i found that the is_ssl() version was affected...

Answer (score 2):

The header that Google Chrome is sending `HTTPS: 1` gets translated into `$_SERVER['HTTP_HTTPS']` on the server side. If you are facing this issue and want a temporary fix, add the following to your wp-config.php file:

```
// Chrome 44 HTTPS:1 header issue temporary fix
$_SERVER['HTTP_HTTPS'] = 0;
```

UPDATE 2015-07-29

as of chrome version 44.0.2403.107 the HTTPS header has been removed and replaced by an `Upgrade-Insecure-Requests: 1` header.

Answer (score 1):

If you can't modify your server configuration, or only for test purpose you can use this chrome plugin [Modify Headers for Google Chrome™](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/modify-headers-for-google/innpjfdalfhpcoinfnehdnbkglpmogdi), go into the plugin and add the action (Modify) with name (HTTPS) and value (0), dont forget to enable it.

That's it, your wordpress website will work like it should be.

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem and I solved it adding the next code at the end of **functions.php** theme file:

```
function https_chrome44fix() {
  $_SERVER['HTTPS'] = false;
}
add_action('init', 'https_chrome44fix',0);
```

Answer (score 0):

Have you use `WooCommerce` in your WordPress? Is `WooCommerce` updated to latest version `2.3.13`?

According [this](https://superuser.com/questions/943842/chrome-adds-weird-https1-header-to-all-requests/#943989) article, There is a problem of Google Chrome HTTPS: 1

I also face this problem but had solve after update `WooCommerce` to latest version, `2.3.13`.

Comment: WooCommerce uses the is_ssl() function of Wordpress, maybe the latest version doesnt uses this function anymore...

Answer (score 0):

This plugin available on GitHub can save you a lot of troubles until the next Chrome version is out.

It basically forces the HTTPS to be false. A fix in Google Chrome will be available in their next release which is planned for 27th July 2015. Until then the plugin should help.

You can view it on GitHub:
https://goo.gl/D54cWv

Cheers