# Wordpress woocomerce redirecting to https in chrome browser

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce

Wordpress with woocomerce plugin (version < 2.3.12) redirects to https when accessed with chrome browser version 44.

The initial request will complete over http, but the resources in the response (css, js, links) will be prefixed by https.

Requests to login will also redirect the https.

A call to `is_ssl()` (wp-included/functions.php) returns true in chrome.

```
function is_ssl() {
    if ( isset($_SERVER['HTTPS']) ) {
        if ( 'on' == strtolower($_SERVER['HTTPS']) )
            return true;
        if ( '1' == $_SERVER['HTTPS'] )
            return true;
    } elseif ( isset($_SERVER['SERVER_PORT']) && ( '443' == $_SERVER['SERVER_PORT'] ) ) {
        return true;
    }
    return false;
}
```

But false in all other tested browsers

Comment: This question has been asked and answered in this previous thread! https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31569988/https-header-issue-with-chrome-version-44-0-2403-xx/31569999?noredirect=1#comment51190710_31569999 Do not edit the plugin core, there is plenty of workarounds for this bug.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is due to combination of Chrome v44 sending a new request header `HTTPS = 1` with every request, and woocomerce version < 2.3.12 incorrectly 
identifying the presence of this header to indicate that the request is being served via an https proxy server.

The code in question can be found in `/wp_content/woocommerce/woocommerce.php`:

```
if ( ! isset( $_SERVER['HTTPS'] ) && ! empty( $_SERVER['HTTP_HTTPS'] ) )
    $_SERVER['HTTPS'] = $_SERVER['HTTP_HTTPS'];
```

To fix the problem, you can comment out these lines (via ftp or on the server directly).

Alternativy, you can upgrade your woocomerce plugin to the latest version (this was fixed in v 2.3.12), either
by using anouther browser to log in to your admin panel, or by upgrading chrome to the latest version.

This was fixed in chrome https://code.google.com/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=505268 and most users are quick to update, 
so this is not likely to be a long term problem, but caused me enough headaches i thought it worth bringing up here

Many thanks to https://ma.ttias.be/chrome-44-sending-https-header-by-mistake-breaking-web-applications-everywhere/